# Defining abbreviations/acronyms in unobtrusive ways

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

There are many complex acronyms that aren't necessarily built from the beginning letter of each sub-unit syllable or word (examples at the end of this post). Sometimes these terms are so common making it clear doesn't matter.  But when defining your own new acronyms for use in a formal publication, whats the best way to help the reader see the selection of letters that is part of the much easier to use acronym?

A point of clarification:  I am not specifically talking about acronyms like "laser" or "scuba" as these have become ubiquitous and even better known than the sequence they actually represent and seem to rarely be defined. I want to reiterate that I am inventing an acronym, and want it clear what combination of letters was selected in the creation of this so that it remains relatively easy to use.  I won't go so far as to say I want it to catch on, but that doesn't mean it hasn't made it easier to use.

I see two options:

- emphasizing the capitals (though this can really look funny, and in science, could even change the meaning, so it's probably not a universal solution, but in cases when it doesn't change the meaning would this really be desirable?)
- use bolds, but really don't think any editor would keep this...

Here are some examples taken from wikipedia and presented with my interpretations of capitals, bolds, and how in a scientific context they may not end up being equivalent:

- Interpol  = **Inter**national Criminal **Pol**ice Organization = INTERnational Criminal POLice Organization
- Gestapo = **Ge**heime **Sta**ats**po**lizei = GEheime STAatsPOlizei
- Amphetamine  = **a**lpha-**m**ethyl**ph**en**et**hyl**amine** != Alpha-MethylPHenEThylAMINE

Comment: I know Google Books doesn't record italicisation, but it ignores non-letters (except insofar as an indexedable "word" is any sequence of letters bounded by non-letters). So if you check out the hits for [Interpol International](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Interpol+Inter%22#q=%22Interpol+International%22&tbm=bks&start=20) you'll find that in many if not *most* of them, the context is the acronym immediately followed by the "definition". Clearly UPPER CASE is [almost?] never used. Personally I think italics/bold is just patronising misuse of modern DTP typesetting features.

Comment: (If I wondered why ***Gestapo*** was thus named, I'd be irritated by someone gleefully "educating" me that it stands for "Geheime Staatspolizei"; I'm not so dumb I can't see the *letters*. I just don't happen to know what "Geheime" means in a foreign language.)

Comment: The examples with bold text are far more legible than those using uppercase.

Comment: 'use bolds, but [I] really don't think any editor would keep this' indicates that you really know where to ask this question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand your point when the word can be researched, but let me try a more complex example: `"full first use then parenthesis abbreviation (FUSTIAN)"`. This FUSTIAN ex. is ludicrous, I am not great at coming up with examples on the spot.I want it to demonstrate that it's a little harder to identify which letters contributed in what order. Obviously, your acronym is context specific and has to fit grammatically, but if it can't be verified anywhere else, I don't think I'm accusing anyone of being dumb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't have a particular editor in mind. This is really just a question during a planning stage.  I'm anticipating a potential problem...  I just thought that in professional publications, random bolds or capitals can be lost so easily - i.e. when only plain text formatting is permitted during a submission (i.e. an online form) or a blanket `small caps` or `all caps`, or `all lower case` type command is issued, you may run into problems if you can't clearly demonstrate the construction of the acronym.  In a way, I am sacrificing ease of definition for acronym usability.

Comment: But ELU deals with real, established English usage. Ways to show how acronyms or initialisms have been devised must be shown in various articles, but the 'best' way is going to be a matter of opinion, and hence an unsuitable question for ELU. It is a matter of orthographic style choice (again off-topic), best addressed by asking editors of articles in the register involved.

Comment: @EngBIRD: Bear in mind that in most contexts, the average reader has no real need to know (or indeed, any real *interest* in knowing) exactly how *amphetamine* is derived from *alpha-methylphenethylamine*, or DNA from deoxyribonucleic acid, for example. I'm a regular visitor to [fifteensquared](http://www.fifteensquared.net/category/guardian/), where some very similar processes are involved in crossword clues. In *that* context it's often helpful to use typography to expose the details *because they matter*, but ordinarily they don't really.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think you hit the nail on the head here (and if you want to make this an answer I would accept it).  The important part is that the reader recognizes the sequence (start to end) of descriptive words that have been condensed (or at least used) in the acronym to serve as a shorter identification or if you will a "proper name".  Whether they dissect the contributing letters correctly, actually doesn't matter.  This isn't a new term I am trying to introduce to the literature.

Answer (score 2):

You have to expect your reader is reasonably intelligent.  They will be able to infer where the acronym came from the same way you did, by seeing.  Therefore simply write:

- The International Criminal Police Organization (Interpol) began investigating...
- The Geheime Staatspolizei (Gestapo) actively engaged in....
- Administering alpha-methylphenethylamine (Amphetamine) to the rats...

Of course, this method is generally used when you go on to refer to the thing as how you cite it in parenthesis later on.  If you do not refer to it again in that manner, then explain it in narrative (e.g., The International Criminal Police Organization, commonly known as Interpol, began investigating...). People don't need italics or bold to see, for example, that "Interpol" is a portmanteau of "international" and "police."